# Powershell: Incorrect return as highest value

Tags: powershell, csv, input

I am using Powershell to parse a CSV file. The CSV file is an inventory of games, including their name, genre, and price. The script's purpose is to run basic inquiries on file input output; this is my typical exercise that I use to practice file input/output with new languages. One of my inquiries is returning unexpected output.

input file:

```
Name,Genre,Price
Age_of_Empires,RTS,19.99
Europa_Universalis_IV,GS,129.99
Skyrim,RPG,60.00
Oblivion,RPG,30.00
Morrowind,RPG,10.00
Call_of_Duty,FPS,60.00
Knights_and_Merchants,RTS,5.00
Halo,FPS,60.00
Empire_Earth,RTS,10.00
Civilization,GS,59.99
Empires_Apart,RTS,10.00
Battlefield,FPS,59.99
Paper_Mario,RPG,2.99
Victoria_II,GS,9.99
Cultures,RPG,7.99
PUBG,FPS,79.99
Crusader_Kings,GS,9.99
```

And here is my script:

```
#Parses data file
#Format: [Name],[Genre],[Price]
$file = Import-Csv .\inventory
echo ""
echo "Welcome to `"GameGO`"! here is our current inventory..."
echo $file #Print out the inventory
Read-Host "Press Enter to continue" #This is only here because it keeps the program from running out of order
do #Use a loop to ask if the user wants to inquire many items
{
    $choice = Read-Host "What would you like to inquiry?"
    #The following blocks of if statements will be used to determine what output to give. Note that the user 
    #will have to know verbatim what commands to give 
    if ($choice -eq "average")
    {
        #Removed for simplicity on Stack Overflow
    }
    elseif ($choice -eq "highest")
    {
        $high = 0          #To be safe?
        $highGame = "null" #Do I have to initalize this to a value?
        ForEach ($line In $file)
        {
            if ($line.Price -gt $high)
            {
                $highGame = $line.Name
                $high = $line.Price
                echo "The new most expensive game is $highGame and it costs $high." #Debug statement!
            }
        }
        echo "The final most expensive game is $highGame and it costs $high." 
    }
    $loop = Read-Host "Would you like to inquire something else? Y\N"
} while ($loop = "Y")
```

My if statement that checks for the highest valued game gives the incorrect value. The incorrect value returned is consistent, but without any pattern that I can recognize.

As the program stands right now:

```
What would you like to inquiry?: highest
The new most expensive game is Age_of_Empires and it costs 19.99.
The new most expensive game is Skyrim and it costs 60.00.
The new most expensive game is Victoria_II and it costs 9.99.
The final most expensive game is Victoria_II and it costs 9.99.
```

I have tried changing the prices around, removing titles, adding new ones, reordering, etc. But no debug test can make a result where I can actually see where my error is. There doesn't seem to be any reasoning to it. I need another pair of eyes on this.

Also, I am having a strange error where the Read-Host commands are causing the script lines to run out of order. Strangely, it is solved by adding the "Press Enter to continue" Read-Host. I am not worried about that now, I only include this explanation to help you understand why that line is included.

Comment: Start by putting your code in a script file (`.ps1` file) and close the ISE. Then open the ISE again, open your script, and run it by typing its name rather than pressing `F5`. This will ensure you are not retaining variables from the last time you ran your script.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Clever idea, but no luck. The same behaviors repeat themselves.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to fix your problem but rather to demonstrate the proper technique for beginning a debugging session using the ISE.

Comment: Very good, duly noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, price is being stored as a string in the csv object. Just cast it to an integer or double and your code works fine!

```
if ([double]$line.Price -gt $high)
```

Basically it was working in alphabetical order, which is why you start with 1, then 6, then 9. It skips Oblivion for instance, because 6 is "further down" the alphabetical list than 3.

Hope this helps explain the issue - it is rather intuitive once you see the issue. By the way, the Reuben is the best sandwich.

Comment: it does indeed work as intended now, thanks. And thank you for the explanation.